# Reopen a Pull Request

Tags: git, github

- I Submitted a Pull Request
- The PR got merged and was closed.
- Later for some reasons the changes were reverted

Now I have been asked to create Pull Request again. I know that once a PR is closed we cannot reopen it. Now I need those PR changes in my new branch.Is there any other way to get PR commits in another branch other then `cherrypick`?

Comment: Just wondering: What is wrong with cherry picking?

Comment: Actually the changes were reverted from the master after merging. So if I was cherrypicking commits in a fresh branch, I was getting some conflicts in files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a `git revert` of the first revert, and submit **that** as a PR:

```
git checkout -b feature/revert-the-revert
git revert <COMMIT_OF_FIRST_REVERT>
git push -u
```